# How to update PHP and install ICU library on CentOS 6.x

Tags: php, linux, symfony, centos, orocrm

I'm trying to install orocrm on centos server and it is asking for PHP 5.4 and ICU library 4.4. Although I updated PHP and restarted Apache my php version still shows PHP 5.3 if outputting phpinfo in a php page. But,if I use php -v command then it shows php 5.5

ini path is shown /usr/local/lib/php.ini if using php page but through command it shows /etc/php.ini

please help...

Comment: ``/usr/local/lib/php.ini`` seems to indicate that someone installed PHP 5.3 by compiling from source, so you have two versions installed

Comment: Can I upgrade that installation?

Comment: You probably shouldn’t even have a manual installation. Figure out how it got installed and remove it. On CentOS I normally use the IUS repository maintained by Rackspace to get a more up to date LAMP stack

Comment: Ah, on re-reading the question I figured out what's going on. Posting an answer

Answer (score 0):

The PHP 5.4 you compiled is not getting picked up by Apache. Rather than figuring out how to point Apache to this installation, the easiest (and safer since you'll get security updates) is to use the [IUS Community](http://iuscommunity.org/pages/About.html) repository

Comment: @Gem you should start a new question, please don't ask me to respond to something I wrote 4 years ago on something that's only tangentially related

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of thoughts. If you're on CentOS you're probably using YUM as your package manager. With it, you could remove the PHP's and add a new one (if you don't have active clients using it). You can search what PHP version yum has by doing one of these:

```
yum list
yum list installed
```

If it registers multiple versions, you can "yum remove $package".

If you're php -v showing version 5.5, then your path is set to include that. You can see that by typing $PATH from the command line when SSH'd in. In your ~/.bashrc (or ~/.profile) you can edit your $PATH by adding something like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

EDIT: You should back up your PATH before writing a new one and after you edit it type "source ~/.bashrc" or "source ~/.profile" to make the command line see it.

You can also directly edit the php in the .bashrc to point to the correct version by setting up an alias (if you don't fix the root of the problem) like

```
alias php="/path/to/php"
```

You can see where your current php is by typing:

```
which php
```

Your PHP extension comes from the apache httpd.conf file. You can find it somewhere like /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. Search for "LoadModule" or "LoadModule php" and see which extension of PHP your apache is pointing to. It may still be pointing to an incorrect version.

To answer your question about ICU, it comes from the "intl" extension. With yum, this is probably called php-intl or php54-intl or php54w-intl. You can do something like "yum search intl" and it should give you the exact extension name.

I hope this helps!